# Python - how to change inbuilt number of days in a month

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime

I produce the following plot:

[image]

With this minimal code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]
test = pd.Series(raw, index=pd.date_range('1-1-2019', periods=len(raw), freq='D'), name = 'MyDebit')
test.plot(grid = True)
plt.show()
```

There are 63 observations, so Python is correctly reading this series as going up to 4th March:

```
31 in Jan-19 
28 in Feb-19 
4  in Mar-19
----
63
```

I am currently working on a seasonal adjustment procedure which requires all months to have 31 days. Now, obviously I could simply use an integer index, and set the major ticks at every 31 observations.

However, I'm looking for a 'purer' solution so that I can display plots with a proper date axis and work with datetime formats.

So, is there a way I can fundamentally alter the numbers of days in the Python calendar such that every month has 31 days (regardless of leap year or not; so every year would have an even 372 days)?

Comment: for what you want to do, "*use an integer index*" sounds as pure as it can get. Modifying Python built-ins not so much.

Comment: Just a thought: Wouldn't it be better to map the values evenly over two months, so that you have slightly more than one value per day? That would still be applicable to planet Earth. 372 days per year is clearly a different planet.

Comment: @MrFuppes - understood, but wondering if there was a way to redefine it.

Comment: @Wups It needs to be one value per day; the non-planet earth days will be empty, to be filled by cubic spline interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to append `number = last-day +1` to the moth's days array for multiple times= `the deference of the day's number and 31`

```
function convertTo31(months):
   if (months.length - 31 = 0):
     return months
   else:
      for (i in range(0,months.length - 31,1)):
        months.append(months[-1]+1)
      return months
```